# fl chart show dates with a custom date format in futter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, fl-chart

i have a list of dates that return dates in full format like this `2021-12-12T11:11:00` .

i'm using `fl_chart` as a library to display dates in this format `Sep20` ; particularly in `bottomTitleWidgets`

I'll provide an image for the desired output .

Here's what i've tried so far

```
SideTitles _bottomTitles() {
return SideTitles(
  showTitles: true,
  interval: 1,
  getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {

   // this outputs the dates like this '2021-12-12T11:11:00'

    final  getdates =
         value.toInt() < widget._entries.length ? widget._entries[value.toInt()].date : "";

    DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.parse(getdates.toString());


    // here i'm formatting dates to be rendered as (Sep22) 
    final finaldates = DateFormat('MMMdd').format(parsedDateTime); 
    
    debugPrint(('FinaleDates \n') + finaldates);

    return SideTitleWidget(axisSide: meta.axisSide, child:  Text('$finaldates'));
  },
);
```

- While return `SideTitleWidget`  , it gives 'invalid date format'.

Her's the desired results :
This is a sample from `charts_flutter` package  .
[image]